# Variadic function int to size_t warning

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic, variadic-functions

I have a function accept multiple arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename... Values>
void doSomething(size_t input, Values... inputs)
{
    size_t len = sizeof...(Values) + 1;
    size_t vals[] = {input, inputs...};

    vector<size_t> n(len);

    std::copy( vals, vals+len, n.data() );

    for(size_t i=0; i<len; i++) cout<<n[i]<<endl; 

    //Do something with n vector
}
```

It works fine when I call this function by:

```
size_t a(1), b(2), c(3);
doSomething(a,b,c);
```

However, it will have a problem when I call this function by:

```
doSomething(1,2,3);
```

It will give out warning message:

```
 warning: narrowing conversion of ‘inputs#0’ from ‘int’ to ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
 size_t vals[] = {inputs...};
```

I do not like this warning message, is there a way to solve this problem? I would like the function to be able to accept either `size_t` or `int`. Thank you.

Comment: `size_t` and `int` are not the same thing.  If you want your function to be able to take an int, you should declare your type parameter to be an int.

Comment: @Falmarri Thank you. I only want my function to take size_t. When I call doSomething(1,2,3), the function automatically transfer 1,2,3 to int. Of course, I can always do size_t a(1), b(2), c(3); doSomething(a,b,c); Is there a easy and a clean way?

Comment: You can do `static_cast<std::size_t>(input)`

Comment: @Zereges  Thank you. The warning comes from `inputs...`, it is not from input.

Comment: Then `{ input, static_cast<std::size_t>(inputs)... }`

Comment: That's because `input` is of type `size_t` and `inputs...` are of type `int`.

Comment: Any particular reasons why your template parameters cannot simply be `size_t ...inputs`?

Comment: Thank you, static_cast works fine.

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik, this function is overloaded. I can also accept other type, e.g. a class. If I only use `size_t ...inputs`, it will not be able to overload.

Comment: The function puts all of its arguments into a vector of `size_t`s. Whatever is being passed, has to be implicitly convertible to a `size_t`. By forcing the conversion to be done when the parameters are passed, this will avoid having to narrow the `int` parameters, and avoid the warning without an ugly `static_cast`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's not valid syntax.